# tex kpathsea cliff notes

Tags: linux, tex

Okay, I know there is a full user guide to [kpathsea](https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Introduction), ls-R files, and path searching in LaTeX; however, I've been at it all day, cannot figure it out, and unfortunately am not able to spend much more time on it. I'm configuring a server (RHEL7) and have installed TeXLive 2019 alongside an older version of texlive (I can't just uninstall the older version for reasons I won't get into).

`tlmgr` installs packages to `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist`, but calling pdflatex still produces an error that it cannot find certain packages (just like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253530/latex-cannot-find-installed-packages) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298794/latex-error-file-multirow-sty-not-found/439103)). I've added the appropriate path to my `.bashrc` file, but I believe the problem is that said packages are getting installed to a location that is not mapped in kpathsea. The example here is multirow.sty: running `tlmgr install multirow` installs the multirow.sty file to the above path, but running `kpsewhich multirow.sty` returns nothing.

Does anyone know of a terse but informative guide to kpathsea, ls-R and how path searching actually works for LaTeX? How do I add the `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist` path so that kpathsea can search there?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding certain paths via `texhash` which is a wrapper for `mktexlsr`, but all that does is add an ls-R file to the path. It doesn't seem to add anything to the `texmf.cnf` file, which kpathsea and kpsewhich uses to find paths.

Comment: Yeah, okay, so that's exactly what I'm looking for. What are the special syntaxes and orders that I have to put into texmf.cnf? I can't seem to find that information in the user guide.